# How do I get all the functions that are available in a Golang package?

Tags: go

How can I get all list of functions that are available in the package, For example in  [time](https://pkg.go.dev/time#pkg-functions) package, When I click the link to list the package functions it is listing only a few functions.

There are functions which are documented under types which are not listed under the package functions.

For example:

```
func ParseDuration(s string) (Duration, error)
```

Which appears under `type Duration` is not listed. I believe this is the case for all the packages in Golang, if this is the case, how can I find out all package functions quickly?

Do you have some tips? Thanks in advance, Naga

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [go doc](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Show_documentation_for_package_or_symbol) command to list functions in a package:

```
go doc -short time | grep "func "
```

Comment: `grep "^[ ]*func "` to ensure matching on the beginning of the line (avoids matching a type definition e.g. `type OAUTHfunc func(string) error`)